# Excel spreadsheet to enter data into a different sheets database

Tags: vba, excel

So i I have created a sheet with text boxes on and a button. the goal is to enter the information into the corresponding text boxes and they populate the database which is on a different sheet. I have managed to create the code that works but there is a small problem. every time i click the button it makes the screen flicker while it copies the data across. It does work but i am wondering if any one can see a way to stop the screen flickering. I am thinking it happens when the data is copied from each of the text boxes. One text box for one flicker or something similar. Tried to write a loop but couldn't work out how to get the different text boxes to be looped through.

The code used is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("database")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
ws.Range("A1").Select


    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
ws.Range("B1").Select


    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox2.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
ws.Range("C1").Select


    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox3.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
ws.Range("D1").Select


    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox4.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
ws.Range("E1").Select


    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox5.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
ws.Range("F1").Select


    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox6.Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("database").Activate
ws.Range("G1").Select


    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True

    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox7.Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` at the start of your sub and then `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by MRig will prevent the flickering you mention but you might want to consider simply not using `.Select` and `ActiveCell` statements.  They can be unreliable and slow.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet 
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("database")
Dim lastRow
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' gets last row in A
ws.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value = TextBox1.Value

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' gets last row in B
ws.Range("B" & lastRow + 1).Value = TextBox2.Value
' ... and so on until

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row ' gets last row in G
ws.Range("G" & lastRow + 1).Value = TextBox7.Value

End Sub
```

This will save all the looping and selecting you were doing so it'll be much faster, and whether or not you include the `Application.ScreenUpdating` the screen won't flicker at all.

Comment: Yeah has worked thanks and why does those .select and .activate make such a difference?

Comment: `.Select` and `.Activate` etc are all actions that directly affect the worksheet's cells and "move" the selected cell around.  All of that requires redrawing the screen (as you'll have seen) but are pretty much totally unnecessary (as you'll now have seen)

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to add solution for ActiveX textboxes

given your actual textboxes names and ranges to fill values with, you could simply go like this:

---

**Solution for worksheet "ActiveX" textboxes** (code goes in the worksheet "database" code pane)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iTB As Long

    For iTB = 1 To 7 '<--| just change "7" to your actual numebre of textboxes
        Cells(Rows.Count, Range("A1").Offset(, iTB - 1)).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = OLEObjects("TextBox" & iTB).Object.Value
    Next iTB
End Sub
```

---

**Solution for Userform textboxes** (code goes in the userform code pane)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iTB As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("database")
        For iTB = 1 To 7 '<--| just change "7" to your actual number of textboxes
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Range("A1").Offset(, iTB - 1)).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & iTB).Value
        Next iTB
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: I just get a compile error saying method or data member not found. It highlights the Me.Controls section. Not sure what this error relates to.

Comment: it's related to the fact that I assumed text boxes belonged to a userform. see edited answer for ActiveX textboxes on the sheet